# How to find length of string variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the length of `i`, which should be 3:

```
Dim k As String
Dim i() As String

k = "test1 l test2 l test3 l"

i() = Split(k, "l")
Debug.Print len(i())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is not a string but an array.  `Len()` returns the **Len**gth of a string.

You want `UBound()`

```
Debug.Print Ubound(i)+1
```

We add `1` because `Split()` creates an `0` base array.

Also it will be 4 as there are three `l` and split will see an empty string at the end of the string.

Comment: As a related note to OP - if you ever want to loop through an array, I suggest using `For x = Lbound(myArray) to Ubound(myArray)` instead of say `For x = 0 to 3`, as it's a little more dynamic and makes sure you use the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `i` has 4 elements if you take a look at them at the Watch window. To get the window in debug-mode, select `i` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> or from View>Watch Window.

[image]

Back to the point, if you want to see the count of the elements of the array, then `Debug.Print UBound(i)+1` would be ok.

Comment: +1 for the Watch Window trick, I never knew that but it'll be a godsend when analyzing arrays!  No longer do I have to make temporary `For` loops just to check their contents! :D

Comment: @BruceWayne - thanks! :) The watch window really saves hours in some other scenarios - xml objects, Excel, Worksheet, Workbook objects. All the properties and values are just a click away - give it a try.